# How can one modify map service legend (specifically raster layer)?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, editing, legend, rest

I've got the raster layer in my map service, which in fact is created automatically by asynchronous GP service as its output result ("View results with a map service" option). The raster is symbolized with graduated colors and then the whole map is exported along with its legend to PDF using printing service.

The thing is that the symbol for the legend, according to rest output and flex app layer list widget, looks like three separated html lines with Hi and Low values as labels next to the first and the last square (yes, symbol for the raster actually consist of three squares). It looks ridiculous in the TOC and on the printout.

Layout in PDF is even worse. It doesn't show the lowest square, probably due to transparency options in map (PNG32 is fine though).

The question is: Can I change its look somehow? I'd like to rename or even get rid of labels (I need it in Polish) and I need one rectangle instead of three split boxes.

I'd like to customize the TOC in the flex app to show "normal" raster symbol at least. Recently I even wanted desperately to remove symbol for this layer from layerlist widget in flexapp but I haven't figured out how to do that so far.